# Why can an unnamed struct not be used as a trailing return type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-errors, trailing-return-type

```
struct { int a, b; } f(int x, int y) // OK
{
    return { x, y };
}

auto g(int x, int y) -> struct { int a, b; } // error C2332
{
    return { x, y };
}

int main()
{
    auto n = f(1, 2).a; // OK
}
```

My compiler is VC++ 2013 RC.

Why is `g` wrong while `f` is OK?

Is this a bug of VC++?

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling this a C++ and not C?

Comment: @Jesse, Yes. I compile it in C++. Otherwise, `auto` will also trigger a compiler error.

Comment: @xmllmx Um, no. `auto` is a valid storage duration specifier in C.

Comment: @H2CO3: But not a valid return type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Definitely :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Couldn't it be somehow coupled with "implicit `int`"?

Comment: @xmllmx: The `auto` keyword is not new; rather, it was re-purposed.

Comment: @Angew NOOOOOOO please just no! (I mean, don't leave out the return type. In this case, the `auto` variable will default to int -- unfortunately.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, I hope not as well; I was just wondering.

Comment: @Angew Yup, that's reasonable.

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course, the C compiler would immediately error out on the (for it) misplaced `->`.

Comment: @Angew Yes, sure. I'm just saying that `auto` would not be the problem, but that's not that relevant anyway :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, in C++, it's illegal to define a type in a parameter or return type, named or not. See C++11[diff.decl]:

> **Change:** In C++, types may not be defined in return or parameter types. In C, these type definitions are allowed

So the actual problem is the first case being accepted, not the second one being rejected.